# Time dilation under constant acceleration

Tags: acceleration, speed-of-light, time-dilation, distance, interstellar-travel

If I am given:

- the distance of two points
- the (constant) force being enacted on the object moving between those two points

how can I figure out:

- the time it would take the object to reach the other point under the forces influence on its position, with zero relative velocity at the destination (essentially that the object starts decelerating half way through its journey) and counting on the speed of light not being surmountable
- the elapsed time from the perspective of the traveling object

The scenario is a spaceship going between stars (the most accurate would probably be a solar sail with a clock onboard), but with the equations such as $t = {\sqrt \frac{2d}{a}}$ the object just, goes faster than light, which is unrealistic to say the least. Of course it counts on using acceleration not force, but I didn't find anything better.

Thanks.

Comment: The unrealism of your conclusion reflects the unrealism of your assumptions.

Comment: @WillO I haven't reached a conclusion yet...

Comment: This is a textbook kinda question. There are solutions you can look up. It is not an easy thing to compute / explain because there is constant acceleration, which in itself is difficult to implement and difficult to extract out of SR and GR, since there is no symmetries to help in the solution.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent could you please point me to a solution, I couldn't find anything, thanks.

Comment: Your conclusion is that the object travels faster than light.  This follows from your assumption that there is an inertial frame in which it can maintain a constant acceleration.  Neither is true.

Comment: @WillO well, I reached the conclusion of it traveling faster than light, because the equation I used didn't count on the speed of light being what it is (i.e. insurmountable), so I am asking for an equation that would take it into consideration. And the acceleration could be achieved with something like a Bussard ramjet.

Comment: oh, sorry, I see now, I confused my acceleration with a constant force. Let me fix it real quick

Comment: You can find equations describing the motion of a ship with constant acceleration here: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html. Take $d=L/2$ where $L$ is the separation between stars, and then the equations are describing the first half of the journey. The second half is given by symmetry, and the rocket decelerates uniformly.

Comment: @Myridium Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted.